# word vba text replacing between arrays

Tags: vba, ms-word, find-replace

I'm trying to populate on array from a CSV file that has spaces between the words and a second one that I'm trying to populate after I have replaced all the spaces with hyphens.

So the contents of array1 looks like this "Hi there" and the contents of array2 looks like this "Hi-there".

I've tried using the replace(text, old, new) but I'm coming across problems. In a standalone macro with no other subs, it works. If there are any other subs it doesn't, throwing up and error saying "wrong number of arguments or invalid property assignment"

This is the code I've got:

```
Private Sub import_csv()

Dim file_name As String
Dim fnum As Integer
Dim whole_file As String
Dim lines As Variant
Dim one_line As Variant
Dim num_rows As Long
Dim num_cols As Long
Dim the_array() As String
Dim imported_array() As String
Dim txt As String
Dim R As Long
Dim C As Long

    file_name = "test.csv"

    'load the file
    fnum = FreeFile
    Open file_name For Input As fnum
    whole_file = Input$(LOF(fnum), #fnum)
    Close fnum

    'Break the file into lines
    lines = Split(whole_file, vbCrLf)

    'Dimension the array
    num_rows = UBound(lines)
    one_line = Split(lines(0), ",")
    num_cols = UBound(one_line)
    ReDim the_array(num_rows, num_cols)
    ReDim imported_array(num_rows, num_cols)

    'Copy the data into the arrays
    For R = 0 To num_rows
        If Len(lines(R)) > 0 Then
            one_line = Split(lines(R), ",")
            For C = 0 To num_cols
                imported_array(R, C) = one_line(C)
                txt = one_line(C)

                txt = replace(txt, " ", "-") '<----- problem line

                the_array(R, C) = txt
            Next C
        End If
    Next R
End Sub
```

Comment: Have you defined a function named "replace" ?  There is already a method with that name in VBA...

Comment: I think I found out what the problem was. I tried using VBA.Replace and it worked. So I went through the references but couldn't find any that were missing :/

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, but this sounds totally weird to me.  You are trying to use Word to do a find/replace in a CSV file?  Is that it?  Why would you even do that?  Here is a typical find/replace in a Word document.

```
Sub FindAndReplaceFirstStoryOfEachType()
  Dim rngStory As Range
  For Each rngStory In ActiveDocument.StoryRanges
    With rngStory.Find
      .Text = "find text"
      .Replacement.Text = "I'm found"
      .Wrap = wdFindContinue
      .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
    End With
  Next rngStory
End Sub
```

That's updating things in the body of a Word document.  Now, if you want to do a find/replace in a data file, whether it is a CSV, TXT, or Excel file, you should probably use Excel for this kind of task.

```
Sub Update_CSV()
    Open "C:\test.csv" For Input As #1
    c0 = Input(LOF(1), #1)
    Close #1

    Open "C:\test.csv" For Output As #1
    Print #1, Replace(c0, "OLD TEXT", "NEW TEXT")
    Close #1
End Sub
```

Comment: I'm trying to create an automated find and replace macro using the comma delimited file to hold the search terms. The plan was, once they have been read into the array, to just let the macro iterate through each search term so the user doesn't have to do a manual find and replace.